# Issue while Exporting products Magento

Tags: magento, export-to-csv, product

When I try to export the product, I get the following error: `No valid data sent`. In the error_log file, I found the following error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Price::getAllOptions() in
>   /app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Abstract.php on
>   line 369

Comment: check your app/etc/config.xml is present

Comment: What should i check in config.xml file. Can you please guide me

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem occured because my **app/etc/config.xml** file was missing. Try to see if your XML's config files are there.

Comment: I have config.xml in etc folder but still the problem exist.

Comment: please share your export product controller and also check if the product controller is override by any other module.

Comment: Can you please guide me how can I check the overridden of product controller? Should i share my website details with you?

Comment: Sure please do that. incase you want drop your email id I will share a php file which can list out all over rides details.

Comment: check email, have dropped you test mail. mail me the details

Comment: I did not receive any email yet. Can you please send email again.

Comment: Please check your email